How to copy an exact version of an app from iPad to iPad?
I have two iPads where I am using a particular app.
On iPad A, I have updated to a new version of the app and discovered that the app has been modified so strongly that it became unusable.
On iPad B, I still have the old version that I am used to, which works perfect for me.
Is there some way to copy the app from iPad B to A, so that I have the desired version on both?
Thanks for any hints!

I've used the commercial iOS/iPad backup utilities iMazing (and iExplorer) to get apps to other locations. It should work with moving an app from one device to another.
